# Get Value From a Listview.builder, then submit that value on another statefeul widget? flutter

Tags: listview, flutter

Hi May i ask a question on how code a function that will get a value from a listview.builder and then forward it to the second screen,

Example

from the picture below,
E.g Selected Item 2 then there should be a button on the bottom where it says submit and on the next screen , it should say that item in the middle of the screen?
and it should be one item only not multi selection,

help me out please, been scratching my head, i understood how the dropdown code work to use setstate and all but i cant figure it to work on listview.builder

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Has my answer helped your issue?

Comment: Is your selection single or multiple ?

Comment: only one selection @NaveenAvidi

Comment: Answer added ! Modify it as your requirement !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 15,
            itemBuilder: (con, ind) {
              return ListTile(
                  title:
                      Text('Item $ind', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        con,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (cc) => OtherScreen(value: 'Item $ind')));
                  });
            }));
  }
}

class OtherScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  //add your custom data
  final String value;

  OtherScreen({Key k, @required this.value}) : super(key: k);

  @override
  _OtherState createState() => _OtherState(value);
}

class _OtherState extends State<OtherScreen> {
  _OtherState(this.data);

  String data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Text(data, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)));
  }
}
```

Comment: let me try to give it a shot

Comment: last question how can i pass multiple data,, for this one it should be one value,, but if there are a few,, on @override
  _OtherState createState() => _OtherState(value,value1, value2);,,,,, and on the state class, _otherstate(this.data1,this.data2,this.data3)... is this it ? :)

Comment: 1. Create a List<DataType> inside first screen and add new selection on tap list item. 2. Create trigger (may be button) to change OtherScreen and pass that List<DataType>

3. Replace String to List<DataType> inside OtherScreen/OtherState

Answer (score 1):

You need to expect the value in your next view:

```
class SecondView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;

  SecondView({this.value});

  @override
  _SecondViewState createState() => _SecondViewState();
}

class _SecondViewState extends State<SecondView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.value),
    );
  }
}
```

And send it on the previous view:

```
void moveToNextView(String name){
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) {
      return SecondView(value: name);
    }
  ));
}
```

Comment: wait,, so next view is the second page? and move to next view is the first one? or am i wrong,, hahaha,, can you do it like first view and second view instead :)

Comment: to further understand nextview is the second one, which it is expecting a code from previous by putting in valuefrompreviousview,, then on the previous one,, i can just put this move to nextview on the onpressed button instead right,, 

OnPressed(value)
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) {
      return NextView(value: value);
    }
  ));,,,, is this right?

Comment: i guess the only thing i dont understand, is that on the first page on your code, the value there is says value: value,, which means on the second page is it supposed to be NextView({this.value}),,, is it supposed to be from the second page that the this.valuefrompreviousview should just simply value?

Comment: @Aia'sBlog I've changed the class name and some of the variables. Please check if it's clearer?

Comment: one last Request , can you this to statefulwidget? :P

Comment: Done. If the answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as correct to help other users, and if you'd like, upvote.

Comment: how can i mark it again? Updated: got it,, really thank ful for all the help